# Why alert() function behaves so strangely?

Tags: javascript

If I run

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}
window.alert('Hello World!');
```

then alert box pops up before for loop gets done.

But instead of using for loop, if I write simply console.log(1).. console.log(1000) statements and then put window.alert('Hello World'). It waits until all the console.log function gets executed.

```
console.log(1)
console.log(2)
.
.
.
console.log(1000)
console.log('Hello World');
```

Both ways of putting console.log statements do the same thing. But behaviour of alert box is different in each situation.

Why it happens so ? If alert is part of web API, shouldn't it get pushed inside the message queue and then pushed to the call stack only (by event loop) when stack becomes empty ? Why alert appears in middle of for loop in first case ?

Comment: The `console` APIs have a degree of asynchronous behavior that varies from browser to browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does alert(); run before console.log();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127173/why-does-alert-run-before-console-log)

Comment: in short: this has nothing to do with `alert`. Console functions get scheduled, so that they do not block the JS thread (unlike `alert`, which is a terrible function that can barely print anything and does block the entire JS thread). They don't execute immediately.

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans : Okay. But isn't alert part of web API ? If that so, why it blocks the JS thread ? Thanks.